# How do I use raw select in Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, illuminate-container

My SQL is something like this:

```
SELECT
  NAME,
  PLACE,
  ETC,
  format(((sum((AMOUNT * U_PRICE)) - ((sum((AMOUNT * U_PRICE)) * 20) / 100)) * 1.18),2) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM
  THE_TABLE
```

And my Eloquent query  is:

```
theTable::select(
    'NAME',
    'PLACE',
    'ETC',
    'format(((sum((AMOUNT * U_PRICE)) - ((sum((AMOUNT * U_PRICE)) * 20) / 100)) * 1.18),2) AS TOTAL_PRICE'
)
->get();
```

But it doesn't work because Eloquent interprets it something like `select name, place, etc, format sum from the_table`.

I have treid to use `DB::raw` but then it says that it didn't expect object.

```
theTable::select(
    'NAME',
    'PLACE',
    'ETC',
    DB::raw('format(((sum((AMOUNT * U_PRICE)) - ((sum((AMOUNT * U_PRICE)) * 20) / 100)) * 1.18),2) AS TOTAL_PRICE')
)
->get();
```

So, how can I use raw SELECT statement in Eloquent?

Answer (score 2):

Use this way

```
DB::table('THE_TABLE')
->select(DB::raw('
  NAME,
  PLACE,
  ETC,
  format(((sum((AMOUNT * U_PRICE)) - ((sum((AMOUNT * U_PRICE)) * 20) / 100)) * 1.18),2) AS TOTAL_PRICE
'))
->get();
```